# How to build .net core project in team city 2020?

Tags: teamcity

I have upgraded my Teamcity build server to Teamcity 2020 and now I am not seeing .Net CLI runner (dotnet). I wasted a day try to fix this but still not resolved.

Does anyone have faced this issue?

Comment: Did you get round to determining what the issue was? Just updated our server to 2020 and the .net CLI support plugin exists, but does not intialize (Failed to initialize Spring Context)

Comment: This may help you https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360008332980-Dotnet-issue-after-update
Also have a look at this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-66138?_ga=2.79401876.1433705353.1593683509-1849589606.1590681404

I did not try, I reverted my upgrade. I tried installing a fresh version and it worked.

Comment: Cheers Vish - sorted it in the end. Worked out that anything to do with .net CLI can simply be ignored as it's now out of date (loads on the net stating to use .net CLI...). The standard ".NET" build runner does the trick..... lol just seen the NikolayP's answer below while typing this :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET cli plugin was renamed to .NET. In the common case TeamCity should convert all .NET cli steps to .NET steps automatically, but  for the case when your had installed a custom version of .NET cli the conversion may not work. If you have few build configurations it is easier to do it manually. It is better to create a backup and to remove custom version of .NET cli before all operations. Otherwise you could create a ticket in the support.